# Arithmethic inside for loop with zero padding for bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, padding

I am trying to write a script which echos `i`, `i + 1` inside a for loop. Also the numbers echoed should be of fixed width 3. I tried

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 10 15)
do
    echo $i
    echo $(( i + 1 ))

done
```

what I get is:

```
8 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14
```

Comment: Numbers beginning with `0` are treated as octal, so `010` is `8`.

Comment: Don't use `seq`; use the C-style `for` loop: `for ((i=10; i<=15; i++)); do`.

Comment: I don't get the same results as you. I get `010 9 011 10 012 11 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the formatting when printing, not when reading the numbers, because numbers beginning with `0` are read as octal.

```
for i in $(seq 10 15)
do
    printf "%03d\n%03d\n" $i $((i+1))
done
```